# Libgdx: Protect Assets

Tags: java, android, encryption, libgdx, assets

I need a way to encrypt my assets in my .jar and my .apk, a way to read from a binary file that is encrypted for a libgdx game.

I know in memory they cannot be protected, but there is a higher level of difficulty for doing that.

Please do you know a way I can convert my assets to a binary file and read from it?

I have seen tons of apps that do this with their apks and obbs for example:

[Heroe Siege Obb](https://www.sendspace.com/file/rxoth0)

Comment: Are you sure those tons of apps do that with libgdx. You also adding a risk of making your game slow by doing extra processing

Comment: @Kumar Saurabh no, they are probably made with unity. I make games for comercial purpose so not adding asset   protection is not an option to me like you.

Comment: I dont know if you referred to it or not but look into this question and specifically into the comment by 'noone' where he talks about creating a password protected zip file.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944391/image-asset-protection-encryption-in-an-android-app